# How to execute dynamic SQL in .net?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write the SQL execute statement below. I'm getting an error in .net saying

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Invalid column name 'Survey'

There is no Survey column which is correct, but what is crazy is that it is getting that value from the `@SurveyNumber` variable. I think my exec code is correct, but maybe I'm not escaping the `@SurveyNumber` properly?

The `@SurveyNumber` variable contains this string "Survey - 1234"

```
@SurveyNumber varchar(50),
@RefIds varchar(max)
AS

Begin
exec('SELECT 
Distinct 
r.DRAWING, 
r.[DESC], 
r.REFMEMO, 
r.OP_PSI, 
r.MAX_PSI, 
r.MAX_TEMP, 
r.DESIGN, 
r.CORR_RATE, 
r.MIN_INSP, 
r.INSP_LOC, 
r.REPL_DATE, 
r.LAST_INSP, 
r.NEXT_INSP, 
r.ALLOW_PSI,
IIf( r.[CF1] is null Or r.[CF1]='''',''Max'', IIf(r.[CF1]=''L'',''Long'',IIf(r.[CF1]=''S'',''Short'',IIf(r.[CF1]=''U'',''User'',''NA''))))AS CF1, 
r.[NF2]*1000 as NF2, 
r.CF2,
r.V_Last_Insp, 
r.V_Next_Insp, 
r.V_Concern, 
r.V_Memo, 
r.V_Report, 
r.V_Interval, 
r.Insulated, 
r.AVG_NEXT_INSP, 
r.AVG_REPL_DATE, 
r.Scaffolding, 
r.Number_Xrays, 
r.MIN_RMS, 
r.DRAWING_FLAG 
From  ref r 
where r.SurveyNumber = ('+@SurveyNumber+') and  r.Id In ('+@RefIds+') 
ORDER BY r.NEXT_INSP asc')
End
```

Comment: `r.SurveyNumber = ('+@SurveyNumber+')` you don't use `=` and `()` and as @SurveyNumber is a string you'll need to use `'''+@SurveyNumber+'''`

Comment: I would urge you not to do this. Code like this is wide open to sql injection. Given how easy it to split a comma delimited string, it’s really not worth the risk.

Comment: Jason, yes I know the risk but this code will not be in the wild. I suppose I could use a split string function or something similar.